# AngularJS: Infinite Scroll in a container

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I'm using [ngInfiniteScroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll) in AngularJS for a specific container.

### Simple example

**html**

```
 <div id="containerInfiniteScroll" class="container">
    <div infinite-scroll="next()" infinite-scroll-disabled="disabled" infinite-scroll-distance="1" infinite-scroll-container='"#containerInfiniteScroll"'>
           <div class="row">
                 <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
                    <span  data-ng-repeat="el in elements | limitTo:limit">
                        {{el}}
                    </span>
                </div>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container{overflow-y:scroll;}
```

**js**

```
//Varibles... 
$scope.elements = ['element1','element2','element3','...','elementn'];
$scope.limit=50;
$scope.disabled = false;

//Function that infinte-scroll calls:
$scope.next = function(){
        $scope.limit=$scope.limit+50;
        $scope.disabled = $scope.limit>=elements.length;
    };
```

The [ngInfiniteScroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll) **works as expected** for `contentInfiniteScroll` content. **Except this case...**

- Don't charge more elements if the scroll-y of the page (*not the
  scroll of the container*) is on bottom.

And only **don't work** in this case...

#### *What am I doing wrong? It's me, or maybe I need to retouch the [library ngInfiniteScroll.js](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/blob/master/build/ng-infinite-scroll.js) ?*

*Thank you.*

Comment: Are there any solution?? :S